# Browser Unable to connect to AWS Hosting

Tags: amazon-web-services

i am new to AWS and i have domain which is registered with another hosting provider. Currently i've tried to connect my domain with AWS by redirecting nameserver to AWS NS but the browser tells unable to connect.

Really need help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you provide more info. Unable to connect to what? An ec2 instance with your website, or some other aws resource?

Comment: Unable to connect to my website. I have already created "RECORD SET" in "Hosted Zones" and all NS value has been copied to my domain NS. But nothing happen

Comment: Does your website works when you use its IP address?

Comment: No. even i try to ping. always request time out

Comment: Am i wrongly configure the ec2, i'm not really sure

Comment: What are security group settings for the instance?

Comment: Let's start from the beginning. Please edit your question to describe what you wish to connect to... for example, is it an Amazon EC2 instance? If so, does the instance work if you go directly to its IP address? Have you allocated a static "Elastic IP address"? Next, how have you configured Amazon Route 53 so far? What type of Record Set have you created? Please update your Question with all these details.

Comment: Yes it's EC2 instance. If i go directly to its IP address, still unable to connect. Elastic ip address not yet allocated. Route 53 already configured.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your domain has correctly transferred to AWS. To help in the transfer I am sharing a  blog here.
https://blog.shikisoft.com/transferring-domain-registrations-from-godaddy-to-amazon-route-53/

Since you have some application running in your AWS EC2 instance, the newly added domain needs to point to that this server.

Follow the below steps to point the EC2 to required domain.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-ec2-instance.html